# How to add a calendar to a TextField in java?

Tags: java, calendar, textfield

I want to add a drop down calendar to a TextField,such that whenever I click on a date on calendar that date should be displayed in the TextField.

Comment: I want a helicopter, but that isn't going to help either of us.  I would suggest you  try doing a search for "date picker", in fact something like "JXDatePicker" might provide you with better results...

Comment: Do you want to do this in web page ? If yes then go for jQuery. It has inbuilt calendar in it

Comment: Swing, Java-FX, SWT, AWT, JEE, JME, GWT..?

Answer (score 0):

Use JSDatePick http://javascriptcalendar.org/
is nice calendar with events, so u can parase manualy date, or calendar will do it.

```
g_calendarObject = new JsDatePick({
        useMode:2,
        target:"deadline",
        dateFormat:"%Y-%m-%d",
    });
```

and u can add event listener (its needed for, parase weeks etc.)

```
g_calendarObject.setOnSelectedDelegate(function(){
    var obj = g_calendarObject.getSelectedDay(); //obj.year, obj.month, obj.day
}
```